# Appending to a list inside of a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm going through a list of individual words and creating a dictionary where the word is the key, and the index of the word is the value.

```
dictionary = {}
for x in wordlist:
    dictionary[x] = wordlist.index(x)
```

This works fine at the moment, but I want more indexes to be added for when the same word is found a second, or third time etc. So if the phrase was "I am going to go to town", I would be looking to create a dictionary like this:

```
{'I': 0, 'am' : 1, 'going' : 2, 'to': (3, 5), 'go' : 4, 'town' : 6}
```

So I suppose I need lists inside the dictionary? And then to append more indexes to them? Any advice on how to accomplish this would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem you're facing is. You can store lists in a dictionary the same way you're already storing numbers in your original code, and you can append to them like you'd append to any list. (That said, [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be a good idea here.)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this way:

```
dictionary = {}
for i, x in enumerate(wordlist):
    dictionary.setdefault(x, []).append(i)
```

Explanation:

- You do not need the call to `index()`. It is more efficient and cooler to use `enumerate()`.
- `dict.setdefault()` uses the first argument as key. If it is not found, inserts the second argument, else it ignores it. Then it returns the (possibly newly inserted) value.
- `list.append()` appends the item to the list.

You will get something like this:

```
{'I': [0], 'am' : [1], 'going' : [2], 'to': [3, 5], 'go' : [4], 'town' : [6]}
```

With lists instead of tuples, and using lists even if it is only one element. I really think it is better this way.

**UPDATE**:

Inspired shamelessly by the comment by @millimoose to the OP (thanks!), this code is nicer and faster, because it does not build a lot of `[]` that are never inserted in the dictionary:

```
import collections
dictionary = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, x in enumerate(wordlist):
    dictionary[x].append(i)
```

Comment: Actually, the `defaultdict` may be slower, rather than faster (because it ends up doing lots of calls to a `__missing__` method implemented in Python), but I doubt there will be much difference either way. And, more importantly, I doubt it will matter in the OP's real-life code. Just use whichever one is more readable.

Comment: From a quick test (with a `random.shuffle`d N copies of /usr/share/dict/words), `defaultdict` is about 30% faster in CPython 3.3, and 20% slower in PyPy 2.0. I actually expected the opposite… but either way, it shows that (a) the difference is pretty small, and (b) you shouldn't rely on your intuition (or, worse, mine!) if you really need to optimize.

Comment: @abarnert: Actually I assumed it was faster because of the docs about `defaultdict`: "This technique is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique using `dict.setdefault()`". Maybe the specifics depend on the ratio of keys / values.

Comment: That makes sense. With almost all unique keys there's little benefit to doing O(M+N/M) instead of O(N) so the constant factor dominates; with very few unique keys it's the other way around. If it matter, I'd do more tests to work out the details. But anyway, when the answers I get come out -20% to +30% for everything I throw at it, that's usually good enough to say "Probably doesn't matter, and if it does, I'd better test with real data", right?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> wl = ['I', 'am', 'going', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'town']
>>> {w: [i for i, x in enumerate(wl) if x == w] for w in wl}
{'town': [6], 'I': [0], 'am': [1], 'to': [3, 5], 'going': [2], 'go': [4]}
```

Comment: This works, but it's quadratic instead of linear. For example, with 20 copies of /usr/share/dict, while rodrigo's two answers take on the order of 3 seconds, your takes many minutes.

Comment: Could do `... w in set(wl)}`

Comment: But then you don't get the index to insert. `enumerate(set(wl))` will give you arbitrary numbers; `set(enumerate(wl))` won't uniquify. You'd need to DSU things into, e.g., a dict mapping values to indices, at which point you've made things far more complicated than the defaultdict version.

Comment: @abarnert: @dansalmo surely meant to apply `set` only to `wl`'s final occurrence, not to the one inside `enumerate`, as in: `{w: [i for i, x in enumerate(wl) if x == w] for w in set(wl)}`. This can reduce execution time a bit, but is still O(n^2).

Comment: @MarioRossi: Well, I guess you can get it down to O(nm) (where m is the number of unique values)… but yeah, that's still not remotely acceptable.

Comment: +1 I expect compilers to do any optimization work for us. Meanwhile, we can use our time in writing clear code. And this one definitely is. A future Python interpreter should be able to assign each `w in wl` to a different processor from an infinite pool and make execution time = O(n) (even if total processing resources will still be O(n^2)). Now, if I catch my current interpreter doing an exceptionally bad job and harming my application software specification (specifically response time requirements), I will jump in and optimize for sure. The OP omits any such information.

Comment: To explain better my point of view, let me say that I also upvoted @rodrigo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are objects, regardless of where they are.

```
dictionary[x] = []
 ...
dictionary[x].append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
dictionary= {}
for i, x in enumerate(wordlist):
    if not x in dictionary : dictionary[x]= []
    dictionary[x].append( i )
```

Comment: this will throw a KeyError if dictionary[x] is not yet defined

Comment: You probably wanted `if not x in dictionary:`, or maybe `if dictionary.get(x, None) == None:`. But either way, while that will give you the _correct_ answer, it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: Also, you almost never want to do `== None` instead of `is None`.

Comment: @Stuart & @abarnert: Absolutely right. Corrections done.  `None` is the default value for `get`'s second parameter, though.  So `dictionary.get(x) is None` would have worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
dictionary= collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, x in enumerate( wordlist ) : 
    dictionary[x].append( i )
```